# Which Hadoop version recommended for HBase 0.90.6?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, nutch

I have no other option than to install HBase 0.90.6 as it is only recommended stable version for Nutch (web crawler) other than 0.90.4.

My question, which Hadoop version is recommended for HBase 0.90.6 to work on pseudo distributed mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out **Hadoop 0.20.205.0** is the compatible version.
I tried Hadoop 1.2.1 but it doesn't seem to work well with HBase 0.90.6